# Image is not centering

Tags: css

I'm trying to centre an image using css and html, however I seem to be missing something. I'm wondering if someone can help me. The image I'm trying to centre falls into #home_top_logos a:

```
/* Uncomment the following to hide the site title */
/*
#site_title {
    display: none;
}
*/
}
#home_top_logos {
    width:950px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:77px;
}
#home_top_logos a {

    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom:54px;
    padding: 25px 0px 20px 0;
}
#home_top_logos p {
    width:811px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin:auto;
    height:75px;
    background:url(../images/old_style_bg1.png) no-repeat;
}
#home_top_logos p a {
    width:366px;
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#616161;

text-align:center;
```

}

Here is the HTML as well:

```
> <div class="wrapper section" id="home_top" data-key="H">  <div
> id="home">        <div id="home_top_botm_bg">             <div id="home_top_inn">
>               <div id="home_top_logos">
>                   <div id="site_title"><a href="#"><img src="images/retro_img1.png" alt="#" /></a></div>
>                   <p><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></p>
>                   <div class="clr"></div>
>               </div>
```

Comment: Show the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: And please add a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: check this : http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/xZ6Pn/

Comment: that didn't work, thanks mostafaznv

Comment: all of this answers working fine ... :/

Comment: Thanks everyone, I solved it. We were using the wrong class in css, it was #site_title, not #home_top_logos a

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Add the display:block; and margin: auto; to your image too:

http://jsfiddle.net/F5av6/5/

```
#home_top_logos img {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: This definitely works for me. I've updated the HTML with yours. The image is centred in the container http://jsfiddle.net/F5av6/5/

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
#home_top_logos a {
    text-align:center;
}

#home_top_logos a img {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/F5av6/3/)

Comment: it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/F5av6/3/ , notice I removed the width from #home_top_logos so the centering will be more clear without the scroll..

Comment: * Also, this applies only to horizontal centering.. if you are talking about vertical centering let us know

Comment: There must be something that I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

you must use `dispaly:block` and `margin:0px auto`

## Demo

**CSS:**

```
#home_top_logos img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

---

**another way:**

set `width` for `img` and use `left` or `right` for that

## Demo

**CSS:**

```
#home_top_logos img {
    position:absolute;
    width:40%;
    left:30%;
}
```

Comment: That threw it behind the image below

Answer (score 0):

You need to add width:100%; and text-align:center; to make this work.

```
#home_top_logos a {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin:auto auto 54px auto;
    padding: 25px 0px 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: there is no text in this though, its an image?

Comment: yes @user3528624 if we user text-align:center; in div and its width is set to width:100%; then it will center all the content in the div including images.the above code it working for me.please add this css and remove old one and then check it.